# Is there a software that "simply" copies files from my pc, from some directories, to a NAS?

Tags: backup

I've buy a NAS and I want to configure my ubuntu to make backup on it.

The problem is that the software installed on ubuntu creates backup compressed, I would like to access files on NAS without decompression, etc.

Is there a software that "simply" copies files from my pc, from some directories, to the NAS?

Or have I to create a little bash file with rsync?

Thanks!

Comment: I know it. I use it every day.. the question was another

Comment: People who voted to close this question because of it is "unclear" what @arrubiu is asking should consider removing the closure vote as there are answers to what he clearly states in the question. If the people haven't faced a situation like this or has not a solution for this or -even worst- they can't understand the question, it's not enough reason to close it down. Thank you.

Comment: I gotta agree on rsync. Awesome utility. Once you get that one command line written to include what you want, and you have an --exclude file to exclude what you don't want, save it a in `.bash_aliases`, and you have everything you need to send it in an instant without re-sending anything that hasn't changed. Set that one command line as a chron job, and it will do it automatically. Set up ssh with public key encryption, and you can do the same over the internet. (That's how my 18 year old daughter's computer gets backed up from the University of Montana to my home in San Diego every day.

Comment: Which software did you try? And what is the NAS model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Back in time sounds like a good choice for your case.

[image]

From the **[Ubuntu Apps Directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/backintime-gnome/)**:

> Back In Time is a framework for rsync, diff and cron for the purpose
>   of taking snapshots and backups of specified folders. It minimizes
>   disk space use by taking a snapshot only if the directory has been
>   changed, and hard links for unmodified files if it has. The user can
>   schedule regular backups using cron.
>
> This is the GNOME front-end for the backintime-common package. If you
>   also install the package nautilus-actions, it can be integrated with
>   the Nautilus file manager to provide context-menu options.

It creates uncompressed backups in the place that you set in the options, allowing you to set useful elements like:

1. Where to save your backups.
2. Schedule

[image]

3. Folders to be included.

[image]

4. Which folders or files you wish not to be included (by name or
   pattern)

[image]

5. Choose the period of time after which a backup will be removed and
   how many backups you wish to keep.

[image]

6. and Other useful options.

[image]

[image]

Once the backups are done, you can gain access to your data via the GUI of Back In Time or by diving inside of your backup folders (see the next screenshot). This way will also allow any other users to access the backup in the NAS from within a different operating system.

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: This could be a good solution but I'm looking for somethine simpler.
The program creates a set of directories too "deep", I think I'll use rsync with a simple bash script. Thanks for the answer!